# Parallel compilation of java classes in runtime

Tags: java, runtime-compilation

I want to compile java classes in runtime in parallel. Since it takes time to compile them sequentially.

I used OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler (https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler, version 2.3.6) to compile and load java classes in runtime.

The result are: Sometimes it works, Sometimes I get LinkageError,  Sometime I get ClassNotFoundException, and Sometimes I get ConcurrentModificationException.

Code:

```
import net.openhft.compiler.CompilerUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ParallelCompilationTest {

    @Test
    public void testParallelCompilation() {
        int parallelism = 10;
        List<String> classes = IntStream.range(0, parallelism)
                .mapToObj(this::createJavaClassCode)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        List<Class> compiledClasses = IntStream.range(0, parallelism)
                .parallel()
                .mapToObj(i -> loadFromJava(classes, i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        compiledClasses.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    private String createJavaClassCode(int i) {
        String codeTemplate = "package mypackage;\n" +
                "public class MyClass[SUFFIX]  {}";
        String code = codeTemplate.replace("[SUFFIX]", i + "");
        return code;
    }

    private Class loadFromJava(List<String> classes, int i) {
        try {
            return CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER.loadFromJava("mypackage.MyClass" + i, classes.get(i));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

When it works:

```
class mypackage.MyClass0
class mypackage.MyClass1
class mypackage.MyClass2
class mypackage.MyClass3
class mypackage.MyClass4
class mypackage.MyClass5
class mypackage.MyClass6
class mypackage.MyClass7
class mypackage.MyClass8
class mypackage.MyClass9
```

LinkageError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:714)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at ParallelCompilationTest.testParallelCompilation(ParallelCompilationTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "mypackage/MyClass7"
    at net.openhft.compiler.CompilerUtils.defineClass(CompilerUtils.java:164)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:157)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:70)
    at ParallelCompilationTest.lambda$testParallelCompilation$0(ParallelCompilationTest.java:22)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:747)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:721)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "mypackage/MyClass7"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CompilerUtils.defineClass(CompilerUtils.java:159)
    ... 16 more
```

ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyClass1

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:714)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at ParallelCompilationTest.testParallelCompilation(ParallelCompilationTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyClass1
    at ParallelCompilationTest.lambda$testParallelCompilation$0(ParallelCompilationTest.java:24)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:747)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:721)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyClass1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:163)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:70)
    at ParallelCompilationTest.lambda$testParallelCompilation$0(ParallelCompilationTest.java:22)
    ... 13 more
```

ConcurrentModificationException:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:714)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at ParallelCompilationTest.testParallelCompilation(ParallelCompilationTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1437)
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:1466)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper.wrapJavaFileObjects(ClientCodeWrapper.java:140)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:132)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.compileFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:101)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:143)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:70)
    at ParallelCompilationTest.lambda$testParallelCompilation$0(ParallelCompilationTest.java:22)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:747)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:721)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

How can I compile classes in parallel?

Comment: Did you try sequential execution rather than in parallel? In other words did you try removing the `.parallel()` ?

Comment: Yes, on sequential execution it works always

Comment: Seems like `CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER.loadFromJava()` is not thread-safe. You might want to contact the library authorl